# Nginx: Why the index directive can't work, 403 forbidden?

Tags: nginx

The `nginx.conf` is as following:

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name example.com;
        root /tmp/test/example;

        location = / {
            index index.html;
        }

        location / {
            root /tmp/test/mydomain;
        }
    }
}
```

The `errors.log` is:
2016/03/22 23:07:56 [error] 17763#0: *1 directory index of "/tmp/test/example/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com:8080"

But when I comment the line `root /tmp/test/example`, it works fine. So I want to know how the `index` redirect works?

Comment: Eeeeu, maybe because `www-data` has not access to that directory ?!

Comment: yeah can you do an ls -la of /tmp/test/example and show us results?

Comment: More than that, `/tmp` `/tmp/test` and `/tmp/test/example` all have to have execute abilities for `www-data` user, not just `/tmp/test/example`

Comment: total 8   
   drwxrwxr-x 2 lizhenguo lizhenguo 4096 Mar 22 23:07 .
   drwxrwxr-x 5 lizhenguo lizhenguo 4096 Mar 22 23:21 ..  Yes, they have read ability@AndrewSmiley

Comment: When I comment the line `root /tmp/test/example`, it works. @JTG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you do not have an `index.html` file in the `/tmp/test/example` directory.

Your `location = /` block tests for the presence of the file (`index.html`), and if it does not exist, generates a 403 response.

After the URI is rewritten to `/index.html` it is actually processed by your `location /` block.

I suspect that the reason it works when you delete the first `root` directive, is because the default (or global) `root` takes over where the "Welcome to nginx" `index.html` file is located. So, it passes the existence test, then serves your file.

*I should add that the above is mostly guesswork based on your observations and my experiments.*

Comment: The URI will be rewritten to `/index.html` to be processed by the next 'location /` block,  why should test for the presence of the file `/tmp/test/example/index.html`.@Richard Smith

Comment: Both location blocks test for the presence of the file. Once when the URI / is processed and again when the URI /index.html is processed.